# yast2 command line option for uinstall

Tags: opensuse

I need to be able to uinstall mariadb that I had installed using the command

```
yast -i mariadb mariadb-tools
```

but for the life of me I can't find the command line option that should be used instead of -i for uinstalling a package. I am new to opensuse and don't really get operations using yast yum or apt-get would have been lovely. Please let me know if what I want is possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Zypper:

```
$ zypper remove mariadb
$ zypper remove mariadb-tools
```

View [this page](http://jrseti.blogspot.com/2011/09/installing-mysql-instead-of-mariadb.html) for more information.